# Unable to process binding knockoutJS

Tags: knockout.js, requirejs

Here is the View Model (auth.js):

```
define(['knockout'], function (ko) {

    var auth = function (isAuth, username) {
        this.isAuth = ko.observable(false);
        this.username = ko.observable(username);
    };

    ko.applyBindings(new auth());

});
```

and View:

```
<li><a href="#" data-bind="visible: isAuth">User</a></li>
```

Also require.configuration

```
var require = {
    baseUrl: '/',
    paths: {
        'bootstrap': 'Scripts/bootstrap/bootstrap',
        'historyjs': 'Scripts/history/jquery.history',
        'jquery': 'Scripts/jquery/jquery-1.9.1',
        'knockout': 'Scripts/knockout/knockout-3.4.2.debug',
        'text': 'Scripts/require/text',
        'pager': 'Scripts/pager/pager',
        'auth':'auth'
    },
    shim: {
        'bootstrap': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        'historyjs': {
            deps:['jquery']
        }
    }
};
```

I keep getting an error on isAuth, I'm new to knockout, so I don't quite understand it.

Comment: Works fine as given: http://codepen.io/pjabbott/pen/yMxEGx Perhaps you could be more explicit than "an error"

Comment: i changed code.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your binding. What does the error say?